# Is he->h_addr_list[0] always the default interface?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

In the gethostbyname call after passing it the result from gethostname..I get a pointer to a hostent struct. If the localhost has several interfaces, is the zero indexed one the default one used when that host sends multicast?

Comment: Is there a default interface? I only know about a default route.

Comment: I think so, I've seen creating udp sockets and then calls to sendto without every specifying an interface..

Comment: If no local interface is specified for sending data from, the interface used depends on the address to sent to and the entries in the routing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no particular ordering of the results. They don't even necessarily correspond to interfaces for the same machine; they might be a number of separate machines serving round-robin for the dns name.